# Limitar la cantidad de filas por hoja de una tabla en PDF con iText7 Proyecto en mvc C# asp.net

Tags: c#, mvc, pdf, itextpdf

Como puedo limitar la cantidad de filas o items por pagina en un documento pdf hecho con itext7 en un proyecto web mvc con asp.net?

estoy imprimiendo una tabla con un foreach, requiero un máximo de 4 filas por cada hoja, es posible limitar esto?

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.